# Different ways to publish Azure function

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have published azure functions from the visual studio by selecting Publish and then selecting all the remaining parameters.
Please share other ways to publish azure function V1 directly on the Azure portal.

I did research but I was unable to understand so if you can please explain in simple terms.
I think there is a way by using CLI or power shell or converting my project to a zip file.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push

Comment: @BowmanZhu thank you for suggesting.I am currently reading 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#cli
.I have few questions.which files should be included in the zip file and what will be the path given. Currently i have azure free subscription.

Comment: Still can not deploy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have other way to publish azure functions.

If you want to use Azure CLI,

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resource_group> -n \
<app_name> --src <zip_file_path>
```

Replace the `<zip_file_path>` placeholder with the path to the location of your .zip file. Also, replace `<app_name>` with the unique name of your function app and replace `<resource_group>` with the name of your resource group.

If you want to use powershell,

```
Publish-AzWebapp -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -Name <app-name> -ArchivePath <zip-file-path>
```

Replace the `<deployment-user>`, `<deployment-password>`, and `<app-name>` placeholders.

---

For example, step to use zip deploy:

**1. create a function app on azure first.**

**2.create a function app on local, and build this function app to dll.**

**3.Go to the Debug folder.**

[image]

**All of this file need to be added to zip.**(The files in bin folder is formed after your function app is compiled, the function1 folder is the declarative file of your function, and the below files are the configuration files of the entire app, and they will be uploaded to Azure. That's what these files do.)

**4. Then for example, using azure cli:**

[image]

**5. Deploy successful !**

[image]

For more information, have a look of the [offcial doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push#cli).

Do I describle clearly?

Comment: i cant see the images ...it is blocking where i work

Comment: @Its_Ady Hi, you can go to the folder of your function, right? So, first click `build` to compile your entire function app. And then go to the bin\Debug\xxx folder of your function app. You will see some folder and files, zip all of them. If you use Release build, just go to the folder in the release folder.

Comment: ok i tried to publish. i am getting error Could not find a part of the path '/home/username/https:/dummyname.file.core.windows.net/test/local.settings.zip'
i  have uploaded the zip file in file share.
Why it is not going to the file url instead it is adding my local user before the actual path

Comment: @Its_Ady Sorry...I Try my best but still cannot reproduce your error, on my side it works well. Does this error comes during your deploy step? And have you change the version of your function on azure? By default, the Function on Azure is V2, I'm not sure if this is the reason.

Comment: @Its_Ady  Oh, I am sorry. I reply false just now. Yes, you need to change the version on portal. Otherwise It can not be publish. Please wait a while, I am outside and using phone to reply, I will update my answer later.

Comment: sure. also my path have spaces in the folder name  . will it affect.? also -n is the function name or the storage account name?

Comment: @Its_Ady  I have not test that. Will reply to you about this.

Comment: Thank you for you help it is deployed successfully now.. The spaces in path does matter even though i have put  in single quotes... your help and effort is appreciated man. thank you. :)
Just clear me one thing  i though -g is the resource name.but i put function name like u said and it worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206037/discussion-between-its-ady-and-bowmanzhu).