# Azure function not deploying using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli

I tried the below command in both bash and powershell getting same error, also why is it looking into /home/radiumball??

In the linux VM infact the zip file is placed in the exact location and still it cannot find file!

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g preprod -n icx-preprod-error-mail --src C:/build_artifacts/data_collection.zip

Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/radiumball/C:/build_artifacts/data_collection.zip'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.9/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 233, in invoke
    cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)
  File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 663, in execute
    raise ex
  File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 726, in _run_jobs_serially
    results.append(self._run_job(expanded_arg, cmd_copy))
  File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 697, in _run_job
    result = cmd_copy(params)
  File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 333, in __call__
    return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
    return op(**command_args)
  File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py", line 580, in enable_zip_deploy_functionapp
    return enable_zip_deploy(cmd, resource_group_name, name, src, timeout, slot)
  File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py", line 607, in enable_zip_deploy
    with open(os.path.realpath(os.path.expanduser(src)), 'rb') as fs:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/radiumball/C:/build_artifacts/data_collection.zip'
```

Update tried to set SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT to true but still not working!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these steps to deploy your function to Azure using Azure CLI:**

Open command prompt=> Navigate to the folder path where your function project(.zip) is available:

[image]

Before deploying function, go to your function app in portal=> Add the application setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true` in `Settings=>Configuration=>Application Settings`.

**Run the below commands:**

***1. az login***

[image]

```
2.az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resource_group_name> -n <function_app_name> --src <your_function_project_name>`
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry did not work please check my original question for update!

Comment: In which location, your function app available? Is it in local?

Comment: No it is in the azure...even the screenshot shows the same...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was asking about your function project(data_collection.zip).

Comment: Try to deploy your function with the above given through command prompt in local instead of bash in Azure portal.

Comment: @RadiumBall, you have your function in local , but trying to access in Azure portal. So, it is not able to recognize the folder/file path of function which is in local. So you have to deploy your function to Azure through Az cli or login to Azure via command prompt and deploy. Refer [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745819/different-ways-to-publish-azure-function)

Comment: The deployment as such is successful with VS and function works fine but when we do a zip deploy using pipeline although deployment is successful the function does not seem to be working, therefore I wanted to debug using Azure CLI but even that is failing as we see above...

Comment: To deploy using Azure CLI, you have to follow the steps I have given in the answer. Login to **Azure** through **command prompt in local**, so that the command will be able to recognize the file path of (.zip).

Comment: No unfortunately not...

Comment: Did you try with command prompt in local instead of bash in Azure?

Comment: Oh yes the local option did work, sorry forgot about that but somehow even that was behaving weirdly, we had call with Microsoft support...nothing concreate came out. For now we have left this option and will be going ahead with VS based deployment

Comment: Can you please rate my question too, then I can mark you answer as helpful